# How do you subclass the file type in Python?

Tags: python, file, subclass

I'm trying to subclass the built-in `file` class in Python to add some extra features to `stdin` and `stdout`.  Here's the code I have so far:

```
class TeeWithTimestamp(file):
    """
    Class used to tee the output of a stream (such as stdout or stderr) into
    another stream, and to add a timestamp to each message printed.
    """

    def __init__(self, file1, file2):
        """Initializes the TeeWithTimestamp"""
        self.file1 = file1
        self.file2 = file2
        self.at_start_of_line = True

    def write(self, text):
        """Writes text to both files, prefixed with a timestamp"""

        if len(text):
            # Add timestamp if at the start of a line; also add [STDERR]
            # for stderr
            if self.at_start_of_line:
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                prefix = now.strftime('[%H:%M:%S] ')
                if self.file1 == sys.__stderr__:
                    prefix += '[STDERR] '
                text = prefix + text

            self.file1.write(text)
            self.file2.write(text)

            self.at_start_of_line = (text[-1] == '\n')
```

The purpose is to add a timestamp to the beginning of each message, and to log everything to a log file.  However, the problem I run into is that if I do this:

```
# log_file has already been opened
sys.stdout = TeeWithTimestamp(sys.stdout, log_file)
```

Then when I try to do `print 'foo'`, I get a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`.  I can't meaningfully call `file.__init__()` in my `__init__()`, since I don't want to open a new file, and I can't assign `self.closed = False` either, since it's a read-only attribute.

How can I modify this so that I can do `print 'foo'`, and so that it supports all of the standard `file` attributes and methods?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Calling `file.__init__` is quite feasible (e.g., on '/dev/null') but no real use because your attempted override of `write` doesn't "take" for the purposes of `print` statements -- the latter internally calls the real `file.write` when it sees that `sys.stdout` is an actual instance of `file` (and by inheriting you've made it so).

`print` doesn't really need any other method except `write`, so making your class inherit from `object` instead of `file` will work.

If you need other file methods (i.e., `print` is not all you're doing), you're best advised to implement them yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what function I'll need, but I'd certainly like to have some of the more commonly used ones implemented.  I guess I'll just bite the bullet and implement the ones I need, and derive from object instead of file.

Comment: What methods besides write are commonly used on sys.stdout? Maybe writelines, close, flush -- all pretty easy (and you'd have to implement them yourself anyway -- how could the file type know to close or flush both of your files anyway?!-)

Comment: Yeah, you're right, upon looking over the file interface, all I really need are write, writelines, close, and flush.  Anything else really should not ever be called on sys.stdout or sys.stderr.

Answer (score 3):

You can as well avoid using `super` :

```
class SuperFile(file):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        file.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

You'll be able to write with it.

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'file' is not defined`.